# Is there any existing solution for generating EF Code First types from a PostgreSQL Database with Npgsql Driver?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, npgsql

I have successfully run some tests with PostgreSQL and EF Code First and I know it works.  I have an existing database that is quite large and it would be helpful if the EF Power Tools Reverse Engineer Code First method worked on my PostgreSQL database, but I can't seem to do that.  I'm assuming its just not supported, but I'm wondering if anyone else has had success with that or perhaps with some other tool/technique for generating EF Code First types and datacontext for PostgreSQL.  Any suggestions?

By the way - I can generate the basic types easily enough off off some information_schema queries against the DB, but I'm shying away from going beyond simple types without navigation properties.  To generate the navigation properties and datacontext and mappings would be more of a pain in the arse and I have a feeling that would just get too hairy.

Comment: The EF Power Tools should work if you have an ADO.NET, DDEX, and EF provider for PostgreSQL installed.

Comment: @bricelam: can you provide details?